# Meteor server side route break subscription

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I've got and Template populate with some data from a Collection.

From this template, i've a button to download a file (from **server side** route).
**After** being routed to this server route (and downloaded the file), the template don't display data anymore. 
I guess the server routing break the subscribtion on the client route, and I can't find a way to fix this...

I'm doing a server side routing to download file from server like:

```
Router.route('/csv/:csvName', {
       name: 'api',
       where: 'server',
       action: function() {
           var filePath = process.env.PWD + '/.scored-categ-csv/' + this.params.csvName;
           var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
           this.response.writeHead(200, {
               'Content-Type': 'text/csv'
           });
           this.response.write(data);
           this.response.end();

       }
    });
```

This route is call from template like:

```
<template name="tabularAnalytics">
<div class="row">
    <a href="/csv/{{metadata.csvPath}}" class="button">Export to Csv</a>
</div>

//When I vizualize this template, data is displayed, but after clicking on the "Export to csv" button, data is not here anymore

{{data}}
</template>
```

Wich take his subscribtion from this route:

```
Router.route('/analytics/tabular/:provider', {
  name: 'tabularAnalytics',
  template: 'tabularAnalytics',
  subscriptions: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe("scoredCategLastByProvider", this.params.provider);
  },
  data: function(){
    return ScoredCategories.findOne({});
  },
  action: function(){
    if(this.ready()){
      this.render();
    }
  }
});
```

Does someone already face this issue?

Comment: you are doing router based subscription. this is why subscription get destroyed after route changed. try to subscribe in the template onCrated function and see what happens

Comment: @Faysal Ahmed It's what I was scared of... But I'm kind of stuck because to subscribe I need to get param from the route, has you can see on the route:  /analytics/tabular/:provider. I guess it is cause of this kind of issue people are switching to View level subscribtion (Flow over Iron router)

Comment: Isn't Iron Router API available in template onCreated function? I almost forgot it's functionality.

Comment: you can with Router.current(), maybe a trick would be possible with that